# How can i add a row in a column layout or is there any best layout to keep all my panels aligned like columns and rows?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am working on Extjs 4.2.1...

How can i add a row in a column layout or is there any best layout to keep all my panels aligned like columns and rows in the same panel?

I have used 5-6 panels in my page(main page - Panel) by referring xtype to its respective views.

**I am struck in here..Can anybody sort this out???**

Note:I have already tried with the table and anchor layout where the size cannot be given dynamically.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking here, can you elaborate?

Comment: Please make a [fiddle](http://fiddle.sencha.com) with what you have and tell us exactly (or make a screenshot and paint into it) what you want.